# iOS EventKit Additional Predicates

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit

I'm building an app that has some iOS calendar functionality built into it. The user can create events and send them to their iCal, but I only want events created in my app to show on the calendar in the app.

I know I can use predicates like below:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [_eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:preferredAppleCalendars];
NSArray *appleEventsArray = [_eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
```

But I also have an array of eventIdentifiers that I would like to add as a condition. So, I want events from the eventstore as above, but only if the event matches an event identifier in my array. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of actually fetching all the events into an array with `eventsMatchingPredicate`, call `enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate`. This allows you to filter out further the results, keeping only the ones you like. Remember to get onto a background thread first!

Comment: perfect, this led me to learning more about enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate which was exactly what I needed.